# Bootstrap 2 : dropdown stay open

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use a dropdown-menu in my website. My test code is:

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dLabel" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" href="/page.html">Dropdown<b class="caret"></b>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
      <li>Item</li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

I want to put this code in my  but it doesn't work. The menu stay open. If i put the code before or after the  the menu work.

Any ideas ?

Edit: The menu doesn't "dropdown". I can see 'Item' without click

Comment: Could you perhaps elaborate a little, or provide a jsfiddle demonstrating what's the problem?

Comment: On jsfiddle, my code is working but when i use it in my website it doesn't. Where can i look to find where is my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a "display: blcok;". I remove it and now it work